# React Router Errors

Tags: reactjs, routes, router

I am having no end of . trouble with my react routes...right now, I'm loading both the show page (AlbumPage) and the index page for my albums (AlbumPane)....whats a guy to do to get the routes to work right?

```
const App = () => (
  <div>
    <AuthRoute exact path="/" component={OfflineHeaderContainer} />
    <AuthRoute exact path="/signup" component={OfflineHeaderContainer} />
    <AuthRoute exact path="/login" component={OfflineHeaderContainer} />
    <AuthRoute path="/" component={Splash} />
    <Route exact path="/home" component={Index}/>
    <Switch>
      <ProtectedRoute exact path="/photos/create" component={Create} />
      <Route path="/photos/:photoID" component={Show} />
      <Route exact path="/albums/:albumID" component={AlbumPage} />
    </Switch>
    <Route path="/albums" componen={AlbumPane} />
    <Route exact path="/users/:userID" component={UserProfileContainer} />
  </div>
);
```

Comment: "routes to work right", how exactly do you mean is working "right"?  What is your exact question?

Comment: You spelled `component` wrong here: `componen={AlbumPane}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you have a few typos, change this:

`<Route path="/albums" componen={AlbumPane} />`

To this:

`<Route exact path="/albums" component={AlbumPane} />`

Then you will only load the route you want when conditionally requesting with an `albumID`